# Induced homomorphisms on fundamental groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Which homomorphism $\pi_1(M) \to \pi_1(N)$ can be realized as induced homomorphism of a continuous map $f:M\to N$?

Comment: What is $\pi^1 (X)$? Is it $\pi_1(X)$?

Answer (score 8):

If $M$ is a one-dimensional Peano continuum and $N$ is a one-dimensional metric space, then the homomorphism is induced by a continuous map $f:M\to N$ up to a basepoint change. This is a result of Katsuya Eda.

The same holds if $M$ and $N$ are planar Peano continua (Greg Conner and Curtis Kent).

These cases do not assume local contractability and are quite non-trivial. The one-dimensional case can be used to show one-dimensional Peano continua with isomorphic fundamental groups are homotopy equivalent.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a simple general answer to this question (I'm assuming here that $M$ and $N$ are reasonable topological spaces like CW complexes). If $N$ is a $K(\pi,1)$, then this is possible. One may map the 2-skeleton of $M$ to $N$ using the homomorphism, and then map the higher skeleta in using the fact that maps of higher dimensional spheres into $N$ are homotopically trivial. This also works if the higher homotopy groups  $\pi_k(N)$ vanish for $2\leq k\leq dim(M)-1$.

Comment: Higher dimensional spheres are not contractible. You mean "simply connected".

Comment: What he means is that all higher dimensional spheres _in $N$_ are contractible.

Comment: Does that rewording fix the confusion?